# delete multiple rows from multiple tables by entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity

I have entity called product,pic and it has properties.

```
public class product 
{
    public virtual int Id;
    public virtual long name;
    public virtual string title;
}

public class pic 
{
    public virtual int Id;
    public virtual int id_pic;
    public virtual string name;
}
```

the relationship between **product(id)** and **pic(id_pic)**.

Now I need to write a method that Delete row from product table.

Comment: Show us your current code and explain how it doesn't match the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If the foreign key in `pic` is referencing a `product`, you should probably name it `id_product`.

Can you post what you've written so far ? You've only posted your two entities and they don't really do anything.

If you're trying to do a cascading delete, where deleting a product also deletes any associated pics, you have several options including regular ADO.NET, Entity Framework and Lightspeed. I would suggest looking at Fluent NHibernate: - http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/